# Why do we need runtime library when writing a compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, runtime

I am following a compiler tutorial. Now I am trying to implement Vector(or array). The author provides a C file including functions to print integer, initialize array(malloc), ect, and ask me to call those functions in my x86 code generated by my compiler.

My question is: why do we need that? can't we use the x86 system call or interrupt?

Is it because by using runtime library, it makes writing compiler easier? but the final executable will be **slower**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a system call or interrupt unless there is something in the system to call, and operating systems don't normally contain vector libraries. You could generate all the code yourself but then you would have to do so in every object file that used the feature, which would be wasteful. So you provide a runtime library of stuff you want the object program to call and arrange so the linker will search it. It is a link-time cost, not a runtime cost.

Comment: Thank you. But how does C implement those features in the first place?